# Jest Unit Test for chained function calls

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs, enzyme, kentico

Its been a while I am struggling with this. New to Unit testing.. I am trying to mock a unit test case for -

```
fetchFooter() {
    client.items().type('footer_link')
            .depthParameter(10)
            .toObservable()
            .subscribe((response) => {
                this.setState({
                    resFooter: response.items,
                    resFooterLinked: response.linkedItems,
                });
            });
}
```

Where client is

```
import { DeliveryClient } from '@kentico/kontent-delivery';

const client = new DeliveryClient({
  projectId: <projectKey>,
  enableAdvancedLogging: false,
});
```

This is what I have written till now, but doesn't seem to work.

```
const sample = {
  items: {},
  linkedItems: {}
};//this is my response object

describe("testing client", () => {
  const mockClient = {
    items: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    type: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    depthParameter: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    toObservable: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    subscribe: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  };

  const mockProps = {
    client: mockClient,
  };
  const component = mount(
    <Footer mockProps={mockProps} resFooter={true} resFooterLinked={true} />
  );

  describe("Component", () => {
    describe("#componentDidMount", () => {
      it("should mount the component and set state correctly", () => {
        const mockedResponse = sample;
        mockClient.subscribe.mockImplementationOnce((handler) => handler(sample));
        // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
        component["setState"] = jest.fn();
        component.instance().fetchFooter();
        expect(
          mockClient.items().type().depthParameter().toObservable().subscribe
        ).toBeCalledWith("footer_link");
        // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
        expect(component["setState"]).toBeCalledWith(sample);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I am getting an error as -

```
    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: "footer_link"

    Number of calls: 0
```

Maybe I am missing some basics here. I searched for a solution for this, but unfortunately didn't find one which can work for me.
Can anyone help with this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the reference](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreturnthis) states, `mockReturnThis` is a shortcut for:

```
jest.fn(function () {
  return this;
});
```

It only makes functions chainable and doesn't pass arguments to next function in a chain. `subscribe` isn't expected to be called with `footer_link`, it's `type` that is called with this argument.

It's unnecessary to make mocked `subscribe` call a handler, this doesn't guarantee that `setState` has been called inside it. Also, `setState` is called not with `sample` but another object.

It's unnecessary to call `expect(mockClient.items()...)` chain in a test, this just increases call count. Call assertions don't allow to determine the order in which methods have been called, this can be secured by hand.

Since mocked client object should be accessible in `config` module mock, the variable needs to be lifted to module scope, this allows to mock `client` in component module.

The chain can be fully tested like:

```
// module scope
jest.mock('../../config', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: mockClient
});

const mockClient = {
  items: jest.fn(),
  type: jest.fn(),
  ...
};
...

// describe scope
let clientCalls;
beforeEach(() => {
  clientCalls = [];

  mockClient.items.mockImplementation(function () { clientCalls.push(1); return this });
  mockClient.type.mockImplementation(function () { clientCalls.push(2); return this });
  ...
});
...

// test scope
component.instance().fetchFooter();

expect(clientCalls).toEqual([1,2,3,4,5]);
expect(mockClient.items).toBeCalledWith();
expect(mockClient.type).toBeCalledWith("footer_link");
...
expect(mockClient.subscribe).toBeCalledWith(expect.any(Function));

let [handler] = mockClient.subscribe.mock.calls[0];
expect(component["setState"]).not.toBeCalled();
handler();
expect(component["setState"]).toBeCalledWith({ resFooter:..., resFooterLinked:...});
```

Comment: the clientCalls gives a blank array. Seems like the mockClient variable is not getting assigned with the object. So I tried defining mockClient as this object at top, but still gives me the error - Number of calls: 0.. Have I missed something?

Comment: It depends on how you mock it, this wasn't shown in the question. If you don't, `mockClient` won't be magically used instead of `client`. Please, show how exactly `client` appears in the component. If it's imported, it should be mocked on module level.

Comment: Oh.. Yes, in component(.js), I have imported client from other file like this - `import client from '../../config';`... So I need to do some changes to test(test.js) for that?

Comment: Yes, you surely do. Also make sure that you reset Jest spies before each test, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#restoremocks-boolean

Comment: That helps.. Thanks a lot!